# Transform: scale reset

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm using `transform: rotate(-2deg);` on a `section`. When the user hovers over the `section`, it changes in size using `transform: scale(1.1);`.

There's one page on my site where I'd like to maintain the rotation, but not the scale when the user hovers over the section. Is there a way to reset `transform: scale(1.1);` without resetting `transform: rotate(-2deg);`?

Here's the code in full:

```
section {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
    /* Rotate */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
    /* Easing */
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
section:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.some-page section:hover {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rqy2jr5y/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the original `transform` value back again on the `hover` selector like given below:

```
.some-page section:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
}
```

This would make sure that the rotation stays at -2 degree but the scale would not happen as this selector is more specific and would take precedence over the other generic `hover` selector.

```css
section {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  /* Rotate */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
  /* Easing */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
section:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.some-page section:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
}

/* Just for demo */

section {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>I'm some content</section>
<div class="some-page">
  <section>I'm some content</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?! Thanks buddy :)

Comment: @Squideyes: Happy to help :) Sometimes we keep looking at the code far too long and miss the most obvious. That's where an extra pair of eyes can help.